# Turn Circle by a specific angle (openGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I like to turn the circle drawn with this class member:

```
void Scene1::Circle(float x_, float y_, float z_, float r){
    xx=r*cos(359 * PI/180.0f);
    xy=r*sin(359 * PI/180.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    for(int j = 0; j < 360; j++)
    {
        glVertex3d(xx+x_,xy+y_,z_);
        glVertex3d(x_,y_,z_);
        xx= r * cos(j * PI/180.0f);
        xy= r * sin(j * PI/180.0f);
        glVertex3d(xx+x_,xy+y_,z_);
        glVertex3d(x_,y_,z_);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

by a specific angle. if i use

```
glRotatef()
```

it is somehow not working. I'd like the Circle to always show his surface to the cam, i want to use it as some sort of Comic-Sphere.
Can anyone Help me?

Comment: How do you use the `glRotatef` function?

Comment: i call it twice. 
`glRotatef(xangle,0,1,0)` 
and
`glRotatef(yangle,1,0,0)`
but nothing happens

Comment: xangle and yangle are global variables which define the cam's direction

Comment: Actually, what result do you expect?

Comment: not in the function, i call the function after i did the rotations

Comment: hmm difficult to explain, i want the circle to always show its surface to the camera, so that you never see the thin side of the circle. it has something to do with a comic-like sphere, so that there's a black border aroundthe sphere

Comment: So you want the circle to always face the camera, and never look squished or bent?

Comment: exactly. that is what i want to do

Comment: Ok, it depends on how you setup your camera, are you using `gluLookAt`?

Comment: Actually the method used to setup the camera isn't relevant, sorry about that. So, I was going to suggest getting the front vector from your modelview matrix, then use it to slide along the front axis of your camera to the distance where you want to put the circle, but maybe the answer given below works?

Comment: The drawing effect you are looking for is called [cel-shading](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel_shading). Since you are rendering a simple surface, maybe you can simply use glLineWidth to render thicker borders, but for more complex effects I suggest [this tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/cel_shading/25001/).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to implement is a so called bill board. This is most easily achieved by setting the upper left 3×3 of the modelview matrix to identity.

If you insist on sticking with OpenGL matrix functions, use `glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, m)` to retrieve it, change the upper left 3×3 elements to identity and use `glLoadMatrix(m)` to put it back into OpenGL. Surround it with glPushMatrix, glPopMatrix to keep the effect local.